# add one number to odd and even integers in a list

Tags: list

I have to iterate through a list using a for loop. In the list, I have to see if the number is even, and if it is, I have to add one to it, and if it is odd, I also have to add one to it. Then i have to print it.

So, the list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and the desired output would be [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11].

```
samplenumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in samplenumber:
     if i%2 == 0:
       print (samplenumber+1)
     else:
       print (samplenumber+1)
```

This is my code above^^

Comment: `print (samplenumber+1)`  ->  `print (i+1)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a) it is not a question b) it looks like homework

Comment: sorry i did not realise you couldnt put schoool work here

Comment: @user You _can_ ask about homework. You post looks ok to me. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

According to your required Answers, the code will be like this:

```
samplenumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in samplenumber:
          
   j=+1
   a=int(i)+ j       
   print (a, end=",")
```